# ChromeDevTools: highlight an item selected by css class?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

The html page is big. All I know is that there is an element with css class `display_json`.

In the dev tools console I can select it like this:

`$('.display_json')`

Is there a simple way to highlight this element, so that I can more easily see it in the html page?

[image: chrome-dev-tools]

Comment: Use a native DOM selection method instead, and hover over the console output: `document.querySelector('.foo_class')`, or type `$('.foo_class')[0]` in the console instead.

Comment: @connexo It works for "body" and "document", but not for the particular `.display_json`.

Comment: @connexo I am very sorry. It was my mistake. `display_json` is an ID, not a css-class. My fault. `$('#display_json')[0]` works fine. What now? Leave the question like this or delete it?

Comment: DevTools Elements inspector can search by CSS/XPath selector in its Find (Ctrl-F) feature.